# Node Js: Exporting available Mongo database names doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am struggling to export available Mongo databases to ./routes/index.js.

Related part of app.js:

```
var ACCESSIBLE_DATABASES = [];
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    assert = require('assert');

var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));

db.open(function(err, db) {
    var existing_databases = [];
    var adminDb = db.admin();

// List all the available databases
    adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        assert.ok(dbs.databases.length > 0);
        ACCESSIBLE_DATABASES = dbs.databases;
        db.close();
    });
});
// Code below export empty array
module.exports.accessible_databases = ACCESSIBLE_DATABASES;

// After some milisec the array has already contain the databases
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(ACCESSIBLE_DATABASES);
}, 100);
```

I'd like to avoid code repetition in my index.js file, but I couldn't achieve it. Import can't work either inside of 'adminDb.listDatabases' function nor later in 'setTimeout' function. (I'd like to use the result later in the app.js file so migrating the code into the index.js file is not an option.

I suggest the reason of it is the asynchronous code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this involves async operations, the way you're trying to export wouldn't work. You'll have to pass a callback to get the databases once the operation has finished.

for eg.

```
function getDBs(db, adminDb, callback) {
   // List all the available databases
   adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
       assert.equal(null, err);
       assert.ok(dbs.databases.length > 0);
       db.close();
       callback(null, dbs);
   });
}

function openHandler(callback) {
    return function(err, db) {
        var adminDb = db.admin();
        getDBs(db, adminDb, callback);
    }
}

module.exports.databases = function(callback) {
    db.open(openHandler(callback));
}

// usage in routes/index.js
const dbs = require('./app').databases;
dbs(function(err, availableDBs) {
    console.log(availableDBs);
});
```

Comment: What "const dbs = require('./dbs');" stands for? I'd like to query existing dbs at launch and set up connections i.e. var monk = require('monk'); var TEST_DB1 = monk('localhost:27017/TEST_DB1'); and also I'd like to export it to avoid code repetitions.

Comment: code-jaff: You understood my problem partly. I'd like to query the existing databases in the app.js file itself to establish the connections to them and make them available to client requests and beside of it I'd also like to import the accessible dbs in index.js file where requests are defined for client side to avoid code redundancy. I can make it in the app file as well, it doesn't matter, but due to async mode building the connections were not happening.

Comment: The solution is working, only one dot is missing from import path: const dbs = require('../app').databases;

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the  `accessible_databases` object before it is initialized.

Try something like this:

```
 var DB_OBJ = {};
 adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.ok(dbs.databases.length > 0);
    //export the array here
    DB_OBJ.accessible_databases = ACCESSIBLE_DATABASES = dbs.databases;
    db.close();
});

module.exports = DB_OBJ;
// After some milisec the array has already contain the databases
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(ACCESSIBLE_DATABASES);
}, 100);
```